# Flutter - change control language simple_month_year_picker

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this inconvenience to change the language of the simple_month_year_picker control, this is my code, thanks in advance, regards

```
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text(
              attendanceService.attendanceHistoryMonth,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            ),
            OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final selectedDate =
                  await SimpleMonthYearPicker.showMonthYearPickerDialog(
                      context: context, disableFuture: true);
                  String pickedMonth =
                  DateFormat('MMMM yyyy').format(selectedDate);
                  attendanceService.attendanceHistoryMonth = pickedMonth;

                },
                child: const Text("Seleccionar mes")),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to set the `locale` field of the parent `MaterialApp` widget. Also, don't forget to add the localization delegates as explained in the library [README](https://pub.dev/packages/month_year_picker).